Stopping line breaks in siunitx qty when using separate-uncertainty
When qty from siunitx is used in text to refer to quantities with separate-uncertainty=true, LaTeX likes to split the value at the plusminus sign, if it improves word spacing.
However, splitting values in half like this leads to poor readability.
I'm aware splitting between the value and unit can be defined, but is there a way to stop line breaks within the value when separate-uncertainty is active?
An example for this (obviously based on the specific font size, margins etc.) would be
In general, line breaks within the value are somewhat rare, with me encountering \qty{1(2)}{breaks} on average when formatting short documents.

which breaks after the plusminus when using a document based on \documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrartcl}.

Looks like an oversight. Unfortunately, there's no interface for changing the symbol used in the case of separate uncertainty.
A hack until the issue is fixed…
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}

\mathchardef\originalpm=\pm
\def\pm{\originalpm\nobreak}

\begin{document}

\noindent
In general, line breaks within the value are somewhat rare,
with me encountering \qty{1(2)}{breaks} on average when formatting short documents.

\end{document}


Here's the output without the hack:


I filed an issue report: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/753
